# how to add new data to existing json file in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, oop, simplejson

i'm trying to add new data to existing json file that named question.json but it's not working! it create a new file, can someone help me please!

mycode: i'm using json-simple1.1

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Main {
    
    public static void writeToJson() {
          JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
          jsonObject.put("question", "q3");
          ArrayList<String>anss = new ArrayList<>();
          anss.add("a1");
          anss.add("a2");
          anss.add("a3");
          anss.add("a4");
          JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();
          
          arr.add(anss.get(0));
          arr.add(anss.get(1));
          arr.add(anss.get(2));
          arr.add(anss.get(3));
          jsonObject.put("answers",arr);
          
          jsonObject.put("correct_ans", "2");
          
          jsonObject.put("level", "2");
          
          jsonObject.put("team", "animal");
          
          try {
              FileWriter file = new FileWriter("json/quetion.json");
              file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
              file.close();
           } catch (IOException e) {
              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
          

    }
    
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        writeToJson();
    }
}
```

```
{
    "questions":[
        {
            "question": "q1",
            "answers": [
                "answer1",
                "answer2",
                "answer3",
                "answer4"
            ],
            "correct_ans": "2",
            "level": "1",
            "team": "animal"
        },
        {
            "question": "q2",
            "answers": [
                "answer1",
                "answer2",
                "answer3",
                "answer4"
            ],
            "correct_ans": "1",
            "level": "2",
            "team": "animal"
        }
    ]
}
```

this is the json file i want to add what i wrote in the code to this json file but i failed! i need someone to tell me how can i add a new json object like {"question" : "q2" ...} without changing the format of the json file or creating a new json file.

Answer (score 0):

## org.json.simple

The structure of your JSON has more levels of nesting than can be observed in your code therefore your result doesn't match.

That's what you have in the JSON:

```
JSONObject { field : JSONArray [ JSONObject { field : value, field : JSONArray, ... }
```

I.e. `JSONObject` which contains a `JSONArray` which might contain several `JSONObject`s which in turn contain a `JSONArray`.

That's how it can be translated into the code (to avoid redundancy logic which for creating a nested `JSONObject` was extracted into a separate method):

```
JSONObject root = new JSONObject();
JSONArray questions = new JSONArray();
        
JSONObject question1 = createQuestion(
    "q1", "2", "1", "animal",
    "answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4"
);
JSONObject question2 = createQuestion(
    "q2", "1", "2", "animal",
    "answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4"
);
        
Collections.addAll(questions, question1, question2);
root.put("questions", questions);
```

```
public static JSONObject createQuestion(String questionId,
                                        String correctAnswer,
                                        String level, String team,
                                        String... answers) {

    JSONObject question = new JSONObject();
    question.put("question", questionId);
    
    JSONArray answersArray = new JSONArray();
    Collections.addAll(answersArray, answers);
    
    question.put("answers", answersArray);
    question.put("correct_ans", correctAnswer);
    question.put("level", level);
    question.put("team", team);
    
    return question;
}
```

That's it.

There's a lot of low-level logic which you can eliminate if you would choose a more mature tool for parsing JSON like Jackson, Gson.

## Jackson

Here's an example using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) library.

Firstly, let's create two POJO: one representing a single question and another wrapping a list of question. For convince, and also in order to avoid posting boilerplate code, I would use *Lombock's*.

*`Question` class:*

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class Question {
    private String questionId;
    private List<String> answers;
    private String correctAnswer;
    private String level;
    private String team;
}
```

*`Questions` class:*

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class Questions {
    private List<Question> questions;
}
```

Here's how such objects can be serialized:

```
Question question3 = Question.builder()
    .questionId("q1")
    .answers(List.of("answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4"))
    .correctAnswer("2")
    .level("1")
    .team("animal")
    .build();
        
Question question4 = Question.builder()
    .questionId("q2")
    .answers(List.of("answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4"))
    .correctAnswer("1")
    .level("2")
    .team("animal")
    .build();
        
Questions questions1 = new Questions(List.of(question3, question4));
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json1 = mapper
    .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
    .writeValueAsString(questions1);
        
System.out.println(json1);
```

*Output:*

```
{
  "questions" : [ {
    "questionId" : "q1",
    "answers" : [ "answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4" ],
    "correctAnswer" : "2",
    "level" : "1",
    "team" : "animal"
  }, {
    "questionId" : "q2",
    "answers" : [ "answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4" ],
    "correctAnswer" : "1",
    "level" : "2",
    "team" : "animal"
  } ]
}
```